How to bypass reCAPTCHA in Firebase phone auth for automated testing in non production environments - React?
I’m currently implementing Firebase phone number authentication with Recaptcha in a React application. However, I need to bypass Recaptcha for automated testing in non-production environments. Below is the relevant code snippet I’m working with:
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    this.getAuth = getAuth(app);
  }

  login(username) {
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    return signInWithPhoneNumber(getAuth(), username, appVerifier);
  }
}


// on login click before otp verification
const login = async () => {
    try {
      await firebase
        .login("+91" + phoneNumber)
        .then((confirmationResult) => {
          setCaptchaVerifier(confirmationResult);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

//initialize captcha window

window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container", {
  size: "invisible",
}, firebase.getAuth);

// on otp verfication
const verifyCode = () => {
  if (!isValidVerificationCode()) {
    setShowInvalidVerificationCode("show");
    return;
  }

  captchaVerifier
    .confirm(code)
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
};


(not a downvoter) Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#create-fictional-phone-numbers-and-verification-codes?

@FrankvanPuffelen. I did in fact not see that. Don't know how i missed that. Thank you so much.

You can specify phone numbers for testing, which are then not affected by quota and (might) bypass the recaptcha. Check the documentation on creating  fictional phone numbers and verification codes to learn more.
